# How to see fetch history and logs after cypress run

Tags: cypress

As a part of my CI pipeline, I am testing my frontend using cypress. I run `cypress run` to test. One test is failing due to failed fetch request. How can I see detailed information about that fetch? So far I could only see which fetch failed from the video recording and screenshots of the test.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the failed url? If so, intercept it.

```js
cy.intercept('/url', (req) => {
  req.on('response', (res) => {
    console.log(res)
  })
})
```

You may have difficulty with nested details, if so

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

or

```js
cy.writeFile('cypress/debug/fetch.json', res))
```